# How to ensure that certain methods are invoked periodically?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

The `System.Threading.Timer` class allows you to periodically invoke a method: the specified method is executed on a thread of the `ThreadPool`. However, If you need to perform a periodic task of high priority, this task can not be performed if there are no more threads available in the `ThreadPool`.

A solution to the above problem could be to use a simple background thread and the `Thread.Sleep` method instead of a `System.Threading.Timer`. Are there other ways to handle this problem? So why does `System.Threading.Timer` class uses the `ThreadPool`?

**UPDATE.** For example, suppose you have an application that needs to handle different categories of activities characterized by different priorities.

- The *periodic activities* have short duration, but they have the highest priority, because they ensure the proper functioning of the application, so it is necessary that it is very likely the presence of an available thread to complete them. This kind of activity could be launched when the application starts.
- The *aperiodic tasks* may have a longer duration. For example: the processing tasks requested from a remote client. The arrival time of these activities could be random, so in this case it would make sense to use the `ThreadPool`.

Here are some examples of periodical activities.

1. An application needs to periodically check if your internet connection is working, then periodically sends a request to a server.
2. A client needs to periodically check if some servers are up and running.
3. A server wants to periodically check the connections to its clients, in order to close the less-used connections.

When there are tasks with different priorities, is it correct managing all these heterogeneous tasks using the `ThreadPool`? Or, should the pool be used to deal with the same kind of activity?

When should I use a dedicated thread to handle a periodic task? When does it make more sense to use the `System.Threading.Timer` class?

**In particular:** when should I not use the `System.Threading.Timer` class to handle a periodic task?

Comment: Doesn't the thread pool normally grow and shrink on its own? Using a thread pool means that you don't have to have dedicated threads for each timer. You can have a dedicated thread, though, if you prefer, and avoid the alleged thread-pool-full issue completely.

Comment: There are lots of questions here, some are unclear and some are too broad in scope. Don't add more examples, just be more specific.

Comment: I improved my question to further clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, messing with thread priorities is a very bad idea (for example on a single processor machine, if your code running on the high priority thread consumes 100% cpu it may cause the machine to become unresponsive as the thread never gets preempted).

Assuming that you ignore the above, then one approach is to start up a thread and set it's priority and use this to periodically do your important processing. For e.g.

```
class Program
    {
        static readonly object Locker = new object();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var importantThread = new Thread(o =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    lock (Locker)
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(Locker, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
                        // do something really really important

                        // if some condition return;
                    }
                }

            }) {Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest};
            importantThread.Start();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 for advice that fretting about thread priorities is only rarely a good idea, and often an indication that you're right at the limit of the platform's capabilities.  If you need actions timed super-accurately or consistently, don't try to do it on a non-realtime OS.

Comment: @WillDean: I do not wish to perform real-time processing on a non-real-time system, but I want to ensure that there is always an available thread for some periodic activities known at design time. Obviously the fact that there is always an available thread does not mean that the task is started immediately, but this is not a problem. What I want to avoid is that the thread pool has no more threads available to perform periodic tasks.

Comment: @enzom83 - then the example in this post is fine - in some environments it's considered profligate to have a thread sitting around mostly unused, but everybody does it a bit.  Don't overestimate the hazards of threadpool exhaustion though - in a lot of environments it just never, ever happens.

Answer (score 0):

I depends on the kind of task/activity you want to execute.

In my opinion i would only use a thread and thread sleep, if it was some kind of real time task, ex. retrieving a value from some hardware at a very precise time.

When using the threadpool, as timers, and parallel task does, you risk that it will slide a bit on every invocation.

The scenarios you are specifying is in my opinion not critical to run as high priority or in a very precise timeframe.

So for every other scenario including yours i would just use tasks or a timer.